# Cant read a value from redux toolkit store on different components

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, redux-toolkit, react-router-redux

I'm trying to create a redux toolkit that store an object so I could read the object values from different components on different react-router path

when calling to read the values that stores in the redux store, I'm getting the initial state I defined in the redux store instead of the updated value. (in this case I'm getting '0')

["login.js"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNGUq.png)

I'm pretty sure it is because of this "window.location.replace('/info');" because when I comment it out and called to read the value from the store (in the same component) it works (it doesn't work only after this line)

["Login.js" Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DB8w.png)

How should I store those values correctly ?
Thank you

Comment: Don't use `window.location.replace` as this reloads your app, and thus likely why you are seeing the initial redux store value. Please update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you reload (this operation append with window.location.replace, the store create with Redux-TK is erase and restart.
You need to you use React-Router (or React-Router-Dom for web) and use navigate to change your path without reload.

https://reactrouter.com